# Can a company using OneDrive for work detect the usage of a personal OneDrive account by an employee on a company machine?

Tags: network, cloud-computing, monitoring

My company is using OneDrive to store all our work files. I occasionally use my personal OneDrive account for personal matters on my work computer with security agents installed. Can a sysadmin detect or separate the use of the personal account? Everything is supposed to be encrypted with HTTPS, so I would think it should not be possible without extraordinary measures, but I would like to be sure.

Comment: TLS doesn't protect you against the owner of the computer. It's meant to protect against third party attackers.

Answer (score 2):

Potentially, yes.

If you are accessing your personal OneDrive from a corporate network then there is a whole class of security products called Cloud Access Security Brokers which can detect and block access to non-approved Cloud services. TThese include the capability to distinguish between known corporate accounts on these services and personal or other accounts.

At a network layer this typically works by passing traffic leaving the corporate network through a transparent intercepting HTTP proxy.  This then adds HTTP headers into requests that indicate to the cloud provider which tenants or accounts the user is allowed to use.

There also exists functionality built into the OneDrive Windows app to allow corporate IT departments to restrict the app to only access the approved corporate OneDrive accounts.  As always with corporate devices, one should assume that your company IT department has full access to the device should they choose to access it.

Comment: Do you have a link or anything about this detection capability?

Comment: Would this also work if I only use the Onedrive website and not the application? Thank you for the insightful reply.

Comment: For Microsoft products, the restriction to specific Azure tenancies can be done by having an intercepting HTTP proxy insert a tenant control http header into requests that list the permitted tenancies.  This would work for both the web and desktop clients. This same approach will send information on failed attempts to the companies Azure logs. See: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/manage-apps/tenant-restrictions